# Ag Grid Column expand issue

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I am using ag grid in my Angular app and it was working fine. My grid has full width on all screen means no horizontal scrollbar in it. The issue  have notice recently is when user double click on shrinked column border it expand the column to full width but it also increase the width of grid.

1. Everytime user double click it increase the grid width that means it should call gridSizeChanged but it never call that function.
2. It increase the grid width and at some point last columns goes behind the screen[image]

I think if it call gridSizeChanged then grid will remian inside screen width and never goes behind the screen.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help without the code

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the code but You could try with
`gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();`

Comment: this is on grid (gridSizeChanged)="GridSizeChanged()" and inside that function this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();

Comment: What about  `suppressHorizontalScroll: false,` didn't you add that accidentally ?

Comment: no, i make it to full width and overflow-x: hidden

Comment: Ok one more idea. Is one of your columns pinned ? Maybe try removing that `pinned` property